# App Engine JPA 2 get error message when deleting an entity "trying to remove detached instance but operation requires it to be attached"

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa

I have a Java App Engine app which stores data using JPA 2. When I attempt to delete an entity I get the error message:

> "...trying to remove detached instance but operation requires it to be
>   attached"

```
/**
 * Delete the customer
 */
protected void deleteCustomer(long id){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    try{
        Customer customer = getCustomerById(id);
        em.remove(customer);
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Utility funciton used to retrieve customers
 */
protected Customer getCustomerById(long id){

    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    try{
        Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Customer.class.getSimpleName(), id);
        return em.find(Customer.class, key);
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same EntityManager class for the find and delete. The was resolved by passing the EntityManager as the original a parameter to the delete function, e.g. (updating the code in the question):

```
/**
 * Delete the customer
 */
protected void deleteCustomer(long id){
    EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();

    try{
        Customer customer = getCustomerById(em, id);
        em.remove(customer);
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Utility funciton used to retrieve a customer by id
 */
protected Customer getCustomerById(EntityManager em, long id){

    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Customer.class.getSimpleName(), id);
    return em.find(Customer.class, key);

}
```